# не понимаю работу getSelectedItem у Spinnera

Tags: android, android-spinner

Столкнулся со следующим, во всех гайдах предлагаемые методы по получению позиции\текста у `spinner` не работают.

```
ArrayAdapter<?> adapter =
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.importance_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


Log.v("итем","item = "+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
switch (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()) {

    case "0":
        Log.v("итем","item = 0");
        intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("importance", "no_matter");

        break;
    case "1":
        Log.v("итем","item = 1");
        intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("importance", "green");
        Log.v("итем","item = 2");
        break;
    case "2":
        intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("importance", "yellow");
        Log.v("итем","item = 3");
        break;
    case "3":
        intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("importance", "red");
        Log.v("итем","item = 4");
        break;
    default:
        intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("importance", "no_matter");
        Log.v("итем","дефолт");
        break;
}
```

Консоль:

```
10-23 22:31:27.153 12415-12415/com.asgard.smartnotes V/итем: item = Не важно
10-23 22:31:27.153 12415-12415/com.asgard.smartnotes V/итем: дефолт
```

Я бы понял, выводись хоть что-то через консоль, не войдя в `switch` - но здесь он попросту на нажатия не реагирует.

Comment: Эмм... если у Вас `spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() == 'Не важно'`, то в `switch-case` будет выполнен `default`.

Comment: @post_zeew дело в том, что логи не показывают значения, которые приходят после смены элемента списка. Я считаю, что вообще ничего не приходит.

Comment: Вы хотите выполнять какое-то действие сразу после того, как пользователь выберет пункт в `spinner`?

Comment: @post_zeew да, собирается интент, сначала проходя через свич, затем остальные данные - и возвращая его в `onActivityResult`, то есть собрать - передать.

Comment: А Вы пробовали на `spinner` устанавливать `listner` выбора пункта? `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener...` и так далее?

Comment: @post_zeew мне кажется это диким костылем, к тому же я не понимаю принцип работы `getSelectedItem()` зачем он в таком случае нужен?

Comment: `OnItemSelectedListener` срабатывает сразу после выбора некоторого пункта `spinner`. А с помощью `getSelectedItem()` Вы можете в любой момент времени получить выбранный айтем.

Comment: И еще: цепочка `getSelectedItem().toString()` возвращает текстовое представление выбранного элемента, если же Вам нужно получить позицию (порядковый номер) выбранного элемента, то воспользуйтесь методом `getSelectedItemPosition()`.

Comment: @post_zeew можете привести пример кода, когда `getSelectedItemPosition()` или `getSelectedItem().toString()` вообще нужен?Он просто тупо оповещает, что этот элемент был выбран - и всё?Либо я всё еще не въехал?

Comment: Ситуация номер раз: необходимо сделать так, чтобы **сразу** после выбора пункта в `spinner` происходило какое-то действие, в таком случае нужно использовать `listener`. Ситуация номер два: есть спиннер и кнопка, **по нажатию на которую** (то есть не сразу после выбора айтема в спиннере) необходимо вывести номер (или текст) выбранного в спиннере пункта, тогда нужно использовать `getSelectedItemPosition()`, либо `getSelectedItem().toString()` в обработчике кнопки.

Comment: @post_zeew теперь понял, оформите как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `getSelectedItem()` класса `Spinner` возвращает выбранный **элемент** `spinner`'а.

Цепочка методов `getSelectedItem().toString()` возвращает **текстовое представление** выбранного элемента.

Метод `getSelectedItemPosition()` возвращает порядковый (нумерация начинается с нуля) **номер** выбранного элемента.